# terraform aws api gateway configure method throttling per each api key

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway

I want to configure usage plan, api key and method like below.

Basically one aws api gateway has 10 methods, i want to configure different rate for each resource

```
usage plan     api key    Resource  Method  Rate (requests per second)
usage plan1    apiKey1    /a        POST    1 qps
usage plan1    apiKey1    /b        POST    2 qps
usage plan2    apiKey2    /a        POST    4 qps
usage plan2    apiKey2    /b        POST    6 qps
```

But in `aws_api_gateway_usage_plan` i can only find usage plan setting for stage.

What terraform resource can i use to configure usage plan

I want to achieve below feature **Configure Method Throttling**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking, i think until now, terraform does not support this feature.

However there is workaround by using aws cli commend.

Refer to this link:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5901

I quoted the work around here

```
variable "method_throttling" {
  type        = "list"
  description = "example method throttling"
  default     = [
    "\\\"/<RESOURCE1>/<METHOD1>\\\":{\\\"rateLimit\\\":400,\\\"burstLimit\\\":150}",
    "\\\"/<RESOURCE2>/<METHOD2>\\\":{\\\"rateLimit\\\":1000,\\\"burstLimit\\\":303}"
  ]
}

# locals
locals {
  # Delimiter for later usage
  delimiter      = "'"

  # Base aws cli command
  base_command   = "aws apigateway update-usage-plan --usage-plan-id ${aws_api_gateway_usage_plan.usage_plan.id} --patch-operations op"

  # Later aws cli command
  base_path      = "path=/apiStages/${var.api_gateway_rest_api_id}:${var.api_gateway_stage_name}/throttle,value"

  # Join method throttling variable to string
  methods_string = "${local.delimiter}\"{${join(",", var.method_throttling)}}\"${local.delimiter}"
}

resource "null_resource" "method_throttling" {
  count = "${length(var.method_throttling) != 0 ? 1 : 0}"

  # create method throttling
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when       = "create"
    command    = "${local.base_command}=add,${local.base_path}=${local.methods_string}"
    on_failure = "continue"
  }

  # edit method throttling
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "${local.base_command}=replace,${local.base_path}=${local.methods_string}"
    on_failure = "fail"
  }  

  # delete method throttling
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = "destroy"
    command = "${local.base_command}=remove,${local.base_path}="    
    on_failure = "fail"
  }

  triggers = {
    usage_plan_change  = "${aws_api_gateway_usage_plan.usage_plan.id}"
    methods_change     = "${local.methods_string}"
  }

  depends_on = [
    "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan.usage_plan"
  ]
}
```